# Why element of a Staggered Grid Layout inside a RecyclerView is automatically Interchanging it's position when loading Images?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I am using RecyclerView in my app to show  images  from the server, I am using Staggered Grid Layout for arrange the images in a Staggered format and also I am using Universal Image Loader to load Images.My problem is ,the positions of images are interchanging while loading from the server,for example, an image shown in the second column will automatically changing to first column and vice versa.I could not understand the reason for this ,can anyone help ?Thanks in advance.

Recycler View and  StaggeredGridLayout

```
     RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager stagGrid = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(rowColumnValue,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rView.setLayoutManager(stagGrid);
```

RecyclerView Adapter.java

```
  public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

private ArrayList<String> itemList;
private ArrayList<String> imageStatusList;
private List<ItemObject> imageList;
private Context context;
String [] imageURLList=null;
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<String> itemList,ArrayList<String> imageStatusList,String [] imageURLs) {

    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.imageStatusList=imageStatusList;

    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentActivity=activity;
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    this.imageURLList=imageURLs;

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true).build();

    // .showImageForEmptyUri(fallback)
    //  .showImageOnFail(fallback)
    // .showImageOnLoading(fallback).build();
    //imageList =  imageLoader.displayImage(itemList,);



}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
    RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView,imageURLList,fragmentActivity);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {


    imageLoader.displayImage(itemList.get(position), holder.recipeImage);
    imageStatusList.toString();

    try {

        if (imageStatusList.get(position).equals("approved")) {
            holder.rimage.setImageDrawable(fragmentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.varified));
        } else if (imageStatusList.get(position).equals("pending")) {
            holder.rimage.setImageDrawable(fragmentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pending));

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return this.itemList.size();

}
}
```

RecyclerViewHolder.java

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{


public ImageView recipeImage,rimage;
int  likeButtonCount;
String [] imageUrls;
Context mContext;
public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView,String [] urlList,Context mContext) {

    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    recipeImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
    rimage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_status_imageview);
    imageUrls=urlList;
    this.mContext=mContext;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position = getPosition();

    ArrayList<String>  imageUrlArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    imageUrlArrayList.add(imageUrls[position]);
    imagePopupWindow(imageUrlArrayList);
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter (Edited)

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

private ArrayList<String> itemList;
private ArrayList<String> imageStatusList;
private List<ItemObject> imageList;
private Context context;
String [] imageURLList=null;
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
DisplayImageOptions options ;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<String> itemList,ArrayList<String> imageStatusList,String [] imageURLs) {

    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.imageStatusList=imageStatusList;

    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentActivity=activity;
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    this.imageURLList=imageURLs;

    options  = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(fragmentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wedcake))
            .showImageOnFail(fragmentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wedcake))
            .showImageOnLoading(fragmentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wedcake)).build();


}
```

onBindViewHolder.java

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {


 //   imageLoader.displayImage(itemList.get(position), holder.recipeImage,options);


    holder.bind(itemList.get(position));
    imageStatusList.toString();

    try {

        if (imageStatusList.get(position).equals("approved")) {
            holder.rimage.setImageDrawable(fragmentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.varified));
        } else if (imageStatusList.get(position).equals("pending")) {
            holder.rimage.setImageDrawable(fragmentActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pending));

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

RecyclerViewHolder.java

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{


public ImageView recipeImage,rimage;
int  likeButtonCount;
String [] imageUrls;
Context mContext;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
DisplayImageOptions options ;
public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView,String [] urlList,Context mContext) {

    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    recipeImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
    rimage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_status_imageview);
    imageUrls=urlList;
    this.mContext=mContext;
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    options  = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wedcake))
            .showImageOnFail(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wedcake))
            .showImageOnLoading(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wedcake)).build();



}
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position = getPosition();

    ArrayList<String>  imageUrlArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    imageUrlArrayList.add(imageUrls[position]);
    imagePopupWindow(imageUrlArrayList);
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void bind(String items){

    imageLoader.displayImage(items, recipeImage, options);
}
```

Comment: Can you try this , in your `onBindViewHolder()` method before setting the original image  try like `holder.setImageBitmap(null)` and then set the original image, Currently what is happening is related to **View Recycling**

Comment: @Satyen Udeshi : Thanks for the response ; I have tried the above snippet, but it is  not solved  my problem .Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

As i am suspecting here , the thing is related to `View Recycling`, you can find many posts in SO itself regarding that, i am posting some code you can try and see if that helps

Declare `DisplayImageOptions options` at class level, and just initialize inside `RecyclerViewAdapter()` constructor, currently you are not using this `options` while loading images, so `UIL` will not load **cached images**. So while loading the images you should do like this :

```
imageLoader.displayImage(item,recipeImage,options);
```

Alternatively you can try the below method also , incase if above doesn't work.

Add a method in your `RecyclerViewHolder` class , for e.g:

```
public void bind(String item){
    // Set your image  here
    imageLoader.displayImage(item,recipeImage,options);
}
```

and in your `onBindViewHolder()` call this method like this ->

```
//  imageLoader.displayImage(itemList.get(position), holder.recipeImage);
holder.bind(itemList.get(position))
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: @Satyan Udeshi : Once agin Thank you very much forthe replay .I have tried that two methods ,I have updated the code above,But still my problem is not solved.Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same behavior with Staggered Grid View and it appears it is related to how items are placed during the layout phase.
The default strategy is `GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS` and according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS), items can be moved inside the layout to hide the gaps that can appear due to the different items sizes.

You can disable this behavior be changing the gap strategy with `setGapStrategy (GAP_HANDLING_NONE)`. This will stop the items changing columns but you may end up with bigger gaps at the start or the end of a column.